# understanding microsoft bot platform

Tags: facebook, telegram, botframework, chatbot

My company has started looking into using a platform to generate chat bots, we came across microsoft's framework and are considering using it. we have a few concerns that we need to understand better about their product and would appreciate it if you could help us.

1) What kind of support do they give us when using Facebook messenger compared to what facebook gives natively? things like quick answer or image sending, buttons on the messages? do they support any of that?

2) We would like if you could elaborate exactly what the platform may give us and why we should use it, what we need is to keep all our logic in our servers and have a platform that will interact with all the messengers for us and keep us from coding to each a different code.

3) like question 1 but for telegram and any other messenger? (custom keyboards and stuff like that).

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @ejadib

Regarding your second question, your bots logic does stay within your bot and your servers. The Bot Framework provides three things:

1) Connectivity services between your bot and the channels your users are on.  All of the logic continues to reside in your bot.

2) Optionally - Bot Building SDK's you can use to facilitate dialog within your bot.  These are SDK's you would code to, but still deploy to your own servers.

3) A directory where you could optionally publish your bot.

As @ejadib says, where we can be consistent across channels we add functionality to the core API; and where functionality is very specific to a channel we expose it through the ChannelData property of the C# SDK (SourceEvent in Node).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1 and 3, if you want to be able to take advantage of special features or concepts for a channel (Facebook/Telegram) BotFramework provide a way for you to send native metadata to that channel giving you much deeper control over how your bot interacts on a channel. The way you do this is to pass extra properties via the ChannelData property (in C#).

Some things are already supported in the framework, for example [Rich Cards](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html) will render differently depending on the channel.

[Here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html) you will find the information (including Facebook and Telegram).

Also, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1077) you can find how for example you can use things like quick replies.

Comment: thank you! i wish i could select 2 answers as the right one :), they together form the answer i was looking for.